How does Ktor (server) handle request timeouts
To my understanding, Ktor (server) handles HTTP-requests inside of coroutines that are dispatched to a thread pool. What happens if a request gets severed for some reason (eg. because of a timeout)? My assumption is that the coroutine handling the request gets canceled, but is that actually the case? I am asking this because I have an HTTP route handler that needs to use a closeable resource, and if my assumptions are correct, I could use the following pattern:
post("some/url") {
    try {
        // Do something with the resource
    } finally {
        withContext(NonCancellable) {
            resource.close() // Note that this is a suspending call, because I am not using a standard Java closeable
        }
    }

    call.respondText("Ok")
}


Since cancellation of coroutines is cooperative in Kotlin, this shouldn't be a problem. Just ignore the cancellation request and do what you have to do to clean up the resource. Cancellation doesn't mean your code is suddenly interrupted. Instead you have to actively check for cancellation and honor that by stopping your code or throwing a CancellationException yourself.
That said, the coroutine specific suspend functions that Kotlin provides, like delay and the sorts, do honor cancellation requests. If you use any of them, they will throw a CancellationException when the coroutine is cancelled while they are executed. I would call it an error though if the implementation of close would honor a cancellation request. Even if it does, I would assume that it knows best, so there is no reason for wrapping it in withContext(NonCancellable). After all, it's the responsibility of close to work correctly when the coroutine is cancelled.
